# Node.JS Upload multiple images to AWS S3 Async

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-s3, upload

I created 2 functions, one for uploading one image and another for uploading multiple images.

Uploading one image is working fine for me while in uploading multiple images, the images are uploaded to S3 and then I'm trying to push to an array each image path, but when I return the array it's empty

```
module.exports = {
async uploadOneFile(image) {
    const params = {
        Key: moment().format('YMMDDHHmmss') + '-' + image.upload.name,
        Bucket: config.get("AwsConfig.bucketName"),
        Body: image.upload.data,
        ContentType: image.upload.mimetype,
        ACL: 'public-read-write'
    };

    await s3.putObject(params).promise();
    return baseURL + params.Key;
},
uploadMultipleFiles(images) {
    const imagesPath = [];

    images.upload.map(async (image) => {
        const params = {
            Key: moment().format('YMMDDHHmmss') + '-' + image.name,
            Bucket: config.get("AwsConfig.bucketName"),
            Body: image.data,
            ContentType: image.mimetype,
            ACL: 'public-read-write'
        };

        await s3.putObject(params).promise();
        imagesPath.push(baseURL + params.Key);
    });

    return imagesPath;
}};
```

I call the function like this:

```
const result = await uploadMultipleFiles(req.files);
console.log(result);
```

And in console output I receive []

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try returning the string on the map and assigning the map return value to the `imagesPath` array?

Like so:

```
uploadMultipleFiles(images) {
    const imagesPath = [];

    imagesPath = images.upload.map(async (image) => {
        const params = {
            Key: moment().format('YMMDDHHmmss') + '-' + image.name,
            Bucket: config.get("AwsConfig.bucketName"),
            Body: image.data,
            ContentType: image.mimetype,
            ACL: 'public-read-write'
        };

        await s3.putObject(params).promise();
        return Promise.resolve(baseURL + params.Key);
    });

    return imagesPath;
}
```

Comment: did not work. I got in console "[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]"

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot about it being with the async keyword, I've edited the answer, but the only thing I've changed is the `return baseURL + params.Key` to `return Promise.resolve(baseURL + params.Key);`, that should do the trick

Comment: Did not help... same output. In Postman I receive an array with empty objects.